# Given a calculated load, what size BTU HVAC do I need?

Tags: hvac

I have created a spreadsheet and for each wall of my space, I calculate a 9,000 BTU load for a 100F day.  This is a 1200 foot warehouse type of area, so it's all one room.  All surfaces have been foamed, and are pretty air tight.

So, if I buy a 9000BTU hvac, that means that it will be maxed out, and that doesn't even account for leaks and other losses.  Obviously I need something larger than 9000BTU.  It seems like I should be more in the 24000-36000 BTU range.

My distilled question is this:  If I calculate exactly 9000BTU load that includes all losses, what sized unit should I buy?

Comment: The true question isn't quite clear -- are you asking for suggestions about the discrepancy between the 9k calculation and the 24k-36k "gut feel" expectation? A recommendation as to the capacity of unit you should buy? Something else? Click the word 'edit' in gray text below the post to revise it.

Comment: Air conditioners don't provide heating unless you buy a heat pump.  Neither provides ventilation.  Will this be a built-in/mini-split, window unit, 2-hose portable or 1-hose portable?

Comment: How much of this load is *sensible* cooling (pulling the temperature down) and how much of this load is *latent* load (condensing moisture/dehumidifying)? Also, have you consulted ACCA Manual S at all?

Comment: You don't want it over-sized either as that will short cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a complete calculation made with reliable input data calls for 9000 Btu/hr, one could use the 9000 unit and anticipate it'll work just about the way the calculations modeled: hold the desired indoor temp when outdoor reaches to 100F. It'll also be able to pull the indoor temp a little lower when outdoor temps are cooler than the design point.

That said.. it might be prudent to round up to the next size, probably 12k Btu/hr.

However, this is all only as good as the building model. If there are heat sources that were modeled wrong or overlooked or might be added in the future then the air conditioning would fall short of expectations, possibly drastically. Sources to consider could include equipment, lighting, people, solar heat gain through windows or skylights, solar exposure on an exterior wall vs shaded warm-air exposure, air infiltration, and humidity control.

Also consider that A/C equipment is rated at specific indoor and outdoor conditions -- the equipment may have reduced capacity under other conditions. Data on this may or may not be available from the manufacturer.

Comment: Thanks.  I do know there are losses, but I did not think of other heat sources.  I also did not think about the performance at a specific temperature.  I can get a much better handle on this now.